# Which one is better approach for doing CRUD operation using CouchDB?

Tags: couchdb

Can anybody help me to find out which is the better approach for doing queries in case of CouchDB?

- Is it making javascript views having a map-reduce function?
- Is it doing mongo expression in Couch DB?

Comment: Which is best depends on your needs and use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mostly want to use Mango. A lot of efforts are put into this new feature to make queries easier to do.

It offers a  lot of query functionalities and in the end, it's backed by views.

For some specific queries, you might have to do map-reduce functions.